# Does JavaScript support automatic type conversion?

Tags: javascript

There are a few expressions that are commonly seen in JavaScript, but which some programming purists will tell you are never a good idea. What these expressions share is their reliance on automatic type conversion — a core feature of JavaScript which is both a strength and a weakness, depending on the circumstances and your point of view.

Comment: What is your *question*? The body indicates that you know the answer to your title is "yes".

Answer (score 2):

`Type coercion` and `type conversion` are similar except `type coercion` is when JavaScript automatically converts a value from one type to another (such as strings to numbers). It's also different in that it will decide how to `coerce` with its own set or rules. I found this example useful because it shows some interesting output behavior illustrating this `coercive` behavior:

```js
const value1 = '5';
const value2 = 9;
let sum = value1 + value2;

console.log(sum);
```

In the above example, JavaScript has coerced the 9 from a number into a string and then concatenated the two values together, resulting in a string of 59. JavaScript had a choice between a string or a number and decided to use a string.

The compiler could have coerced the 5 into a number and returned a sum of 14, but it did not. To return this result, you'd have to explicitly convert the 5 to a number using the Number() method:

```js
sum = Number(value1) + value2;
```

From an MDN glossary entry I wrote here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion edited by [chrisdavidmills](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/profiles/chrisdavidmills)

Answer (score 0):

> Does JavaScript support automatic type conversion?

Yes. It's usually called type *coercion*, but conversion is perfectly accurate.

For instance:

```
console.log("Example " + 42);
```

"automatically" converts 42 (a number) to string. I put "automatically" in quotes because it's done by the `+` operator, in a clearly-defined way.

Another example is that various operations expecting numbers will convert from string (or even from object). For instance:

```js
const obj = {
    valueOf() {
        return 2;
    }
};
const str = "10";
console.log(Math.max(obj, str)); // 10
console.log(Math.min(obj, str)); // 2
```

The rules JavaScript uses are clearly and completely defined in the specification. That doesn't prevent people from frequently being surprised by some of them, such as that `+""` is `0`.